# Tool recommendation for data flow mapping on attribute level

Tags: attributes, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking for a good way to document the data flow / mapping in our project.

Basically we have a number of Input sources, where we get data from, either 3rd party services or our own web-frontend where the user enters information.

We aggregate and store this data in our own data-model in a database and then need to send it to a number of other services for further processing, like performing an eligibility check, printing some documents, feeding back information to the initial system and so on

Of course every 3rd party service has defined there own data-structures and I'm looking for a way to document how they align.

Simplified example
Initial system sends us the name as `customer.personalData.firstName`
In our data structure we store it as `customerData.firstName`
Eligibility check will get it as `customer.firstName`
To archiving system it is send as attribute "name".

In total we have about 300 attributes that we receive, process and forward and no one has an overview of where data is coming from and going to.

So, quite often we're asked things like. Where is the data you send to document generation coming from or is the attribute we get from Initial system even used anywhere.

Any recommendations for tools or templates?